# Py code for API call using username, password and API endpoint url

Tags: python, webhooks, api-design

I wanted to write a API call for downloading data from a CRM platform.

I only the below information:

1. API endpoint
2. Username
3. Password
4. Userid

I see two ways of doing the same:

1. Using Webhooks
2. get statement with encryption

For 1, I have written the below code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
# Define your webhook endpoint URL (without the full URL)
WEBHOOK_URL = "/webhook"
# Store received webhook data in memory (for demonstration purposes)
webhook_data = []
# Replace these with your actual credentials
EXPECTED_USERNAME = "xxxx"
EXPECTED_PASSWORD = "yyyy"
# Webhook handler
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL, methods=["GET"])
def handle_webhook():
# Verify the request sender (replace with your authentication mechanism)
auth_username = request.headers.get("Username")
auth_password = request.headers.get("Password")

if auth_username != EXPECTED_USERNAME or auth_password != EXPECTED_PASSWORD:
    return jsonify({"message": "Authentication failed"}), 401

# Process incoming webhook data (this is where you can store it or perform other actions)
data = request.json  # Assuming the data is in JSON format
webhook_data.append(data)

return jsonify({"message": "Webhook received successfully"}), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(port=5000)  # Run the Flask app on port 5000 (adjust as needed)
```

For 2, the below code also throws error:

```
import requests

user = "xxxx"
password = "yyyy"

response = requests.get('https://media.xxxxxxx.com/GatewayAPI/rest?userid=200XXXXX&encrdata=  {{Base64_Encoded_Encrypted_ Data}}', auth=(user, password))
data = response.json()
```

Kindly help me with the correct code here. Any help will be appreciated.
P.S. - Sorry for the long message. I have started learning Python only a week back.

Expected Result: Data download in JSON format.